# Neo4j comunity backup and recovery from corrupted db

Tags: neo4j, backup, recovery

Is neo4j community version usable to store any valuable data ? I started small project to store data in this db and I was surprised how easy is to implement custom ORM and work with transactions. I gather data for some months, but I had unclean shutdown of my db. Some relations got corrupted and then I realized that community version is missing essential tools like online backup, restore and recover db.

I think that Neo guys are trying too hard to push toward enterprise. So anybody, would you recommend Neo db (strictly community) for business project ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for repairing stores that should work with community versions : https://github.com/jexp/store-utils

For your last question, I don't think Neo4j differ from [other databases](https://www.mysql.com/support/), if you need support then you'll need a license.

An unclean shutdown is caused by **something** and would have probably the same effect on enterprise version.

Is it safe to rely on strict community version of neo4j: yes as it is safe to rely on mysql community version.